# Como verificar se existe um dado especifico em um array multidimensional C#

Tags: c#

Trabalho em uma escola que faz o controle de frequência dos alunos pela digital, cada vez que um aluno "bate" o dedo é adicionado a um código a um txt, se o aluno bateu 1 vez é registrado entrada se ele bateu 2 vezes é marcado entrada e a saída, consegui ler o text e salvar os dados no array TodosApontamento[12,31,X] que no caso séria Mês e dia, agora preciso verificar se cada aluno bateu uma ou duas vezes no dia

Fiz um script para salvar dados de um txt em um array multidimensional, cada linha do txt contem um código que é salvo no array, preciso verificar se esse código aparece 2 vezes no mesmo índice do array, por exemplo: array[dia,mes,codigo] porem não sei como fazer isso, obs: fiz uma lista também para futuramente salvar os dados no banco.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MetroFramework;
using MetroFramework.Forms;
using System.IO; //declarando a biblioteca de entrada e saída de arquivos
                 //a biblioteca IO

namespace Pj_FrquenciaObjetivo
{
    public partial class TratarDados : MetroFramework.Forms.MetroForm
    {
        public TratarDados()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TratarDados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int  qtMaxima = 0;
                int  Coutap = 0;


                //declarando a variavel do tipo StreamWriter 
                StreamReader x;

                //Colocando o caminho fisico 
                string Caminho = "C:\\Apontamento\\Apontamento.txt";

                //abrindo um arquivo texto
                x = File.OpenText(Caminho);
                while (x.EndOfStream != true)//quer dizer que não chegou no fim do  
                                             //arquivo
                {
                    string linha2 = x.ReadLine();

                    if (linha2 == "")
                    {
                        x.Close();
                        break;

                    }
                    qtMaxima++;

                }
                string[,,] TodosApontamento = new string[12,31, qtMaxima];

                x = File.OpenText(Caminho);
                string recuperaDia ="", recuperaMes ="";

                //enquanto nao retornar valor booleano true 
                while (x.EndOfStream != true)//quer dizer que não chegou no fim do  
                                             //arquivo
                {

                    //le conteúdo da linha
                    string linha = x.ReadLine();


                    //escreve na tela o conteúdo da linha
                    // Aqui eu devo salvar o texto em pedaços para
                    // que eu possa criar o obj apontamento
                    string status = linha.Substring(0, 2);
                    string dia = linha.Substring(2, 2);
                    string mes = linha.Substring(4, 2);
                    string ano = linha.Substring(6, 4);
                    string hora = linha.Substring(10, 2);
                    string minuto = linha.Substring(12, 2);
                    string segundo = linha.Substring(14, 2);
                    string matricula = linha.Substring(16, 5);

                    if (recuperaMes==mes && recuperaDia==dia)
                    {
                        Coutap = 0;
                    }
                    while (TodosApontamento[int.Parse(mes), int.Parse(dia), Coutap] !=null)
                    {
                        Coutap++;
                    }
                    TodosApontamento[int.Parse(mes),int.Parse(dia), Coutap] = linha;
                    Apontamento apm = new Apontamento(status, dia, mes, ano, hora, minuto, segundo, matricula);  
                    Controller.CarregaApontamentos(apm);

                  //  MessageBox.Show("Mes: "+int.Parse(mes)+" - Dia: "+ int.Parse(dia) + " - Arrey : "+Coutap +" - Conteudo: "+ TodosApontamento[int.Parse(mes), int.Parse(dia), Coutap]) ;
                    Coutap++;
                    recuperaDia = dia;
                    recuperaMes = mes;
                }

                //após sair do while, é porque leu todo o conteúdo, então
                //temos que fechar o arquivo texto que está aberto
                x.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {


                MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Erro ao tentar adicionar na lista.", "Atenção", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

        }

        private void btn_voltar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Home Hhome = new Home();
            this.Hide(); // use dessa maneira.
            Hhome.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void metroButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Apontamento criado com seucesso");
            MessageBox.Show("A quantidade de apontamentos é :" + Controller.L_apontamento1.Count());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu acho que seria melhor você serializar seu objeto e salvar ele como `XML` ou `JSON`. E quando for ler, deserializar para objeto.

Comment: Explica seu problema porque não dá pra entender o que você quer fazer com a matriz.

Comment: você quer verificar se algum valor repete na mesma coluna em linhas diferentes?

Comment: isso @LeandroAngelo

Comment: E como você vai querer indicar ou apresentar isso?

Comment: @MarceloUchimura trabalho em uma escola que faz o controle de frequência dos alunos pela digital, cada vez que um aluno "bate" o dedo é adicionado a um código a um txt, se o aluno bateu 1 vez é registrado entrada se ele bateu 2 vezes é marcado entrada e a saída, consegui ler o text e salvar os dados no array TodosApontamento[12,31,X] que no caso séria Mês e dia, agora preciso verificar se cada aluno bateu uma ou duas vezes no dia

Comment: @LeandroAngelo quero fazer essa verificação e caso tenha apenas 1 "apontamento" do mesmo aluno no dia eu vou criar uma "apontamento" e salvar no txt

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim: faça

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
```

no topo do .cs.

Crie uma classe privada dentro da classe `TratarDados`,

```
private class Frequencia : IEquatable<Frequencia>
{
    DateTime Data { get; private set; }
    string Matricula { get; private set; }
    int QuantidadeBatidasCatraca { get; private set; }

    public Frequencia(DateTime data, string matricula) : this(data, matricula, 1)
    { }

    public Frequencia(DateTime data, string matricula, int batidas)
    {
        Data = data;
        Matricula = matricula;
        QuantidadeBatidasCatraca = batidas;
    }

    // Implementação do contrato.
    public bool Equals(Frequencia other)
    {
        return other.Data == Data &&
            other.Matricula == Matricula;
    }

    // Sobre-escreve o método padrão.
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Data.GetHashCode() ^ Matricula.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

No método abaixo, faça o seguinte:

```
private void TratarDados_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Lê todas as linhas do arquivo especificado.
    string[] linhas = 
        System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\apontamento\apontamento.txt");

    // Declara uma lista de frequências.
    List<Frequencia> freqs = new List<Frequencia>();

    foreach (string linha in linhas)
    {
        string status = linha.Substring(0, 2);
        string dia = linha.Substring(2, 2);
        string mes = linha.Substring(4, 2);
        string ano = linha.Substring(6, 4);
        string hora = linha.Substring(10, 2);
        string minuto = linha.Substring(12, 2);
        string segundo = linha.Substring(14, 2);

        string matricula = linha.Substring(16, 5);
        DateTime data = 
            new DateTime(int.Parse(ano), int.Parse(mes), int.Parse(dia));

        Frequencia freq = new Frequencia(data, matricula);
        freqs.Add(freq);
    }

    // Manipula a lista de frequencias.
    var query =
        freqs
            .GroupBy(g => g)
            .Select(s => 
                new Frequencia(s.Key.Data, s.Key.Matricula, s.Count()))
            .OrderBy(o => o.Data)
            .ThenBy(t => t.Matricula);

    foreach (Frequencia f in query)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Data {0}, Matricula {1}, Frequencia {2}",
            f.Data, f.Matricula, f.QuantidadeBatidasCatraca);
    }
}
```

Debugue no Visual Studio e, depois da execução, veja a janela Output (Saída).